# C++ nested loops with variables outside

Tags: c++, loops, gcc

this is definitely silly question, which already answered multiple times but I'm really confused and cannot find out how to google.
I have approximately 4 years of experience in software developments, but that thing overwhelmed me:

```
int x1 = 2, x2 = 5;
int y1 = 2, y2 = 5;
for (; x1 <= x2; x1++) {
    for (; y1 <= y2; y1++) {
        cout << x1 << " : " << y1 << endl;
    }
}
```

the result is

```
2 : 2
2 : 3
2 : 4
2 : 5
```

But I was expecting to see:

```
2 : 2
2 : 3
2 : 4
2 : 5
3 : 2
3 : 3
3 : 4
...
5 : 4
5 : 5
```

I mean **x1** was not updated even once.

I think this some how related with outer scope and compiler optimization. Clarify me please.

Comment: So you are expecting `y1` to somehow become `2` again after the inner loop finishes?

Comment: That somehow could happen if you move `int y1 = 2, y2 = 5;` inside the outer loop.

Comment: or just initialize y1 within the for statement, as is common.

Comment: @GauravSehgal x1 never become more than 2 after inner lopp finishes

Comment: omg ahah I see that now

Comment: stupid situation I should delete that question

Comment: @IvanTalalaev Why do you think so? Your `cout` statement is inside inner loop. Inner loop was never entered after the first iteration of the outer loop (due to `y1` never being reset). Such behavior could've been caught in the act if you used your debugger to step through your code. Since you have 4-year experience - you should know how to use one.

Comment: "4 years of experience in software developments" then it's long overdue to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: @bolov :-D 3 am now, sleep 2 hours last night

Comment: ok waste question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't reset the y1.

```
int x1 = 2, x2 = 5;
int y2 = 5;
for (; x1 <= x2; x1++) {
    for (y1 = 2; y1 <= y2; y1++) { // This resets y1 every time the loop starts
        cout << x1 << " : " << y1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Or

```
int x1 = 2, x2 = 5;
int y1 = 2, y2 = 5;
for (; x1 <= x2; x1++) {
    y1 = 2;
    for (; y1 <= y2; y1++) {
        cout << x1 << " : " << y1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the reason you should code your `for` loop like below to avoid this kind of side effect so that you should not forget to reinitialized counter variable in this case `y1`. Also declaring and initializing a counter variable out side `for` loop not going to give you any advantage. So always try to avoid this kind of implementation and follow the below approach:

```
int x2 = 5;
int y2 = 5;
for (int x1 = 2; x1 <= x2; x1++) {
    for (int y1 = 2; y1 <= y2; y1++) {
        cout << x1 << " : " << y1 << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This behaviour is correct.**

After the nested loop you never set `y1=2;` again, so `cout << x1 << ":" << y1 endl` will never run again because y1 is 6 when the nested loop has ended and therefore does not fit the condition (`y1 <= y2`) given in the nested loop.

Edit: For working code see the comment from [user9335240](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48784800/8578404)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `inner for-loop`.
When in first iteration(when `x1` is `2`) you get the printed result i.e.

```
2 : 2
2 : 3
2 : 4
2 : 5
```

Since, you have not re-initialized the `y2` variable so, in all subsequent iterations of inner loop the condition `y1 <= y2` is evaluated to `false`(at this time `y2` is `6` in this case). So you are not getting output as you expect.

You can confirm this by following modified code:

```
int x1 = 2, x2 = 5;
int y1 = 2, y2 = 5;
for (; x1 <= x2; x1++) 
{
    for (; y1 <= y2; y1++) 
    {
        cout << x1 << " : " << y1 << endl;
    }
    cout<<"In outer loop with x1="<<x1<<" and y1="<<y1<<endl;
}
```

You will get following output:

```
Point 1: In outer loop with x1=2 and y1=2
2 : 2
2 : 3
2 : 4
2 : 5
Point 2: In outer loop with x1=2 and y1=6
Point 1: In outer loop with x1=3 and y1=6
Point 2: In outer loop with x1=3 and y1=6
Point 1: In outer loop with x1=4 and y1=6
Point 2: In outer loop with x1=4 and y1=6
Point 1: In outer loop with x1=5 and y1=6
Point 2: In outer loop with x1=5 and y1=6
```

To get output as you expect, re-initialize `y1` to `2` in inner-loop. i.e. change inner loop from `for (; y1 <= y2; y1++)` to `for (y1 = 2; y1 <= y2; y1++)`

Answer (score 0):

you should reset the value of y1,it can be done by the above steps as posted or like this one:

```
int x1 = 2, x2 = 5;
int y2 = 5;
for (; x1 <= x2; x1++) {
for (; y1 <= y2; y1++) { // This resets y1 every time the loop  starts
    cout << x1 << " : " << y1 << endl;
}
y1 = 2;
}
```